# My code don't run after create .exe, only open the window

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When i use VSCODE it works very clean.

OBS: I'M using pyinstaller to create .exe

Probably it isn't compiling my imgs to .exe, but how i can solve this?

https://github.com/jeffersondenzer/reddit/blob/main/lolbotlobby

Comment: Please see [ask] to improve this question. Can you provide more of your code in the question?

Comment: my code is this o github, and my problem is exatly wat i say .-.

Comment: Can you create a [mre] for this and include it in the question instead of linking it? Creating a [mre] is also really helpful with debugging a problem. You may be able to answer your question yourself.